# Angularjs Populate a select box by selecting two fields in different select boxes

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs, hibernate

I have 3 select boxes in total. I will select values in 2 select boxes and will click on Submit button. What will be the process to populate the 3rd select box from this. I have data in tables and I am using hibernate in backend. What will be my js file, will the call be post or get. Please help me and give whole procedure.I am using angularjs on frontend side. Please tell me the content of js file as well as the modifications in HTML file. Thank you.

```
    <form name="deviceForm" ng-submit="submitForm()">
<div class="container" style="margin-top:10px">

<div class="row" style="margin-top:20px">
<div class="col-sm-3" align="right">
<h4>Device Family<super style="color:red">*</super></h4>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2" align="left">
<select class="form-control" ng-model="device.family">
        <option>Device 1</option>
        <option>Device 2</option>
        <option>Device 3</option>
        <option>Device 4</option>
        <option>Device 5</option>

      </select>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-3" align="right">
<h4>Device Type<super style="color:red">*</super></h4>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2" align="right">
<select class="form-control" ng-model="device.type">
        <option>Type 1</option>
        <option>Type 2</option>

      </select>

</div>
</div>
</div>


<div align="center" style="margin-top:30px">
<button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-info ">Show Devices</button>
</div>
</form>
```

This is my HTML. 
Now after submitting , how would I write in js file to send these Selected options.

Comment: Never ask `whole` procedure here [because...](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) it cause people to vote down your question until it locks.


Now, paste your template first. On the other hand, using `GET` or `POST` only matters on how you configured the server-side to handle that request

Comment: question updated..

Comment: What you need is `how to use controllers with forms` right?

Comment: I'm not seeing your third select box

Answer (score 0):

With the stinginess of informations you have proved, this is the most I can do:

```
(() =>
{
    'use strict';
    angular.module('app', [/**'ng-routing'**/])
    .controller('DeviceController', [function ()
    {
        var self = this;
        // self.forms.new
        // OR                   ... angular will handle this for me
        // self.forms.edit
        self.storage = {}; // to store raw data from service or anywhere, needed for the form initialization
        self.storage.types = [{id: 1, label: 'Type 1'}, {id: 2, label: 'Type 2'}, {id: 3, label: 'Type 3'}, {id: 4, label: 'Type 4'}, {id: 5, label: 'Type 5'}];
        self.storage.families = [{id: 1, label: 'Device 1'}, {id: 2, label: 'Device 2'}, {id: 3, label: 'Device 3'}, {id: 4, label: 'Device 4'}, {id: 5, label: 'Device 5'}];

        self.events = {};
        self.events.typeChanged = self.events.familyChanged = function ()
        {
            self.storage.theThird = undefined; // this will be used to disable submit button while the value is not set, or any service result is waited to set the value


            var type = self.data.type || 0;
            var family = self.data.family || 0;
            if (0 === (type * family) % 2) // you may implement any logic as needed. IF SYNTAX is just an example
            {// this code executes only if the `id` at least one of `selected type` or `selected family` is even
                self.storage.theThird = [{id: 2, label: '2016-02'}, {id: 4, label: '2016-04'}, {id: 6, label: '2016-06'}, {id: 8, label: '2016-08'}, {id: 10, label: '2016-10'}, {id: 12, label: '2016-12'}];
            }
            else
            {
                self.storage.theThird = [{id: 1, label: '2016-01'}, {id: 3, label: '2016-03'}, {id: 5, label: '2016-05'}, {id: 7, label: '2016-07'}, {id: 9, label: '2016-09'}, {id: 11, label: '2016-11'}];
            }
        }
    }]);
})();
```

...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" ng-app="app" ng-cloak ng-strict-di>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>{{app.title}}</title>
        <script src="web/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="web/libs/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="web/js/javascript.js"></script>
        <style>
            label.optional:after
            {
                content: '*';
                color: red;
            }
            /**  Folowing style are just to ease the viewing of changes  **/
            main {display: flex; flex-direction: row-reverse}
            main > aside {flex-grow: 1}
            main > form {flex-shrink: 1}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- You may declare your controller this way, or leave it to the responsibility of your router -->
        <main ng-controller="DeviceController as ctrl">
            <aside>
                <pre>{{ctrl|json}}</pre>
            </aside>
            <form name="ctrl.forms.new"> <!-- This way, we can access our form inside the controller -->
                <div>
                    <label for="new-device-family">
                        Family
                    </label>
                    <select
                        id="new-device-family"
                        ng-model="ctrl.data.family"
                        ng-change="ctrl.events.familyChanged()"
                        ng-options="family.id as family.label for family in ctrl.storage.families">
                        <option></option> <!-- this empty option will allow an unselected state -->
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="new-device-type" class="optional">
                        Type
                    </label>
                    <select
                        id="new-device-type"
                        ng-model="ctrl.data.type"
                        ng-change="ctrl.events.typeChanged()"
                        ng-options="type.id as type.label for type in ctrl.storage.types">
                        <option></option> <!-- this empty option will allow an unselected state -->
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="new-device-the-third">
                        The Thrid
                    </label>
                    <select
                        id="new-device-the-third"
                        ng-model="ctrl.data.theThird"
                        ng-options="theThird.id as theThird.label for theThird in ctrl.storage.theThird">
                        <option></option> <!-- this empty option will allow an unselected state -->
                    </select>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <button type="reset" ng-click="ctrl.forms.new.$setPristine(); ctrl.forms.new.$setUntouched()">
                    Reset
                </button>
                <button type="sumbit" ng-disabled="!ctrl.data.theThird"> <!-- Disabled if the third is any falsy value -->
                    Reset
                </button>
            </form>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```